# show multiple R graphics windows in (r)gedit

Tags: r, plot, gedit

I'm using rgedit plugin for gedit.
I would like to allow more than one graphic (plot) window to show at a time. Currently, whenever I `plot()`, the plot overwrites the previous plot window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a `gedit` issue but a general R feature -- use `x11()` (or `windows()`) to create new plot devices.

You can then use `dev.set()` et al to flip between them.

Comment: can I set it to be done automatically instead of manually each time?

Comment: Sure. You could write your own function `myplot(...)` that calls `dev.new()` before calling `plot()` with the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Dirk's answer, you can also plot multiple graphs in the same window, look at `?par`, in particular at the `mfrow` parameter

For instance `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` will give you a 2x2 layout for your plot.

For more complex layouts see `?split.screen` and `?layout`

---

To switch between devices you can do:

```
# Create 3 plots
dev.new()  # Or X11()
dev.1 <- as.integer(dev.cur())
dev.new()
dev.2 <- as.integer(dev.cur())
dev.new()
dev.3 <- as.integer(dev.cur())

x <- seq(1, 100, 0.1)

# Switch to device 1
dev.set(dev.1)
plot(x, sin(x), "l")
# Switch to device 3
dev.set(dev.3)
plot(x, cos(x), "l")
# Add something to graph #1
dev.set(dev.1)
points(x, cos(x), "l", col="red")
```

Note that, although the devices numbers you're storing in `dev.1`, `dev.2` and `dev.3` will mostly be sequential (1,2,3) you should always use `dev.cur` to get the number of the device, as you cannot safely assume they will be exactly 1,2,3 etc... (you may have other devices open)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could open a new console tab, but this isn't as elegant (you have to submit your code twice) as the suggestions made by Dirk and nico.